# Update row for specific column on Webform App

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table which contains recipe for each item. Actually I wanted to update my specific column in the table. This table contains Item ID,Stock Code,Stock Name,Stock Group Name,Stock Unit Name,Amount Needed indexes. First of all ı could update and it is working, but when I want to update only my Amount column but when I press edit button, the TextBox opens for each columns. I want only amount row for the TextBox open.

This is the code:

```xml
     <asp:GridView ID="grdItems" runat="server" DataKeyNames="_IdItemHam" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="False" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="Horizontal" OnRowDeleting="grdItems_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="grdItems_RowEdit" meta:resourcekey="GridView5Resource1" >
                <Columns>
                  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" BackColor="DarkRed" style="color: White" />
                           <%--   <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" BackColor="Green" style="color: White" />
                               --%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="OnUpdate" BackColor="Green" style="color: White" />
                            <asp:Button Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="OnCancel" BackColor="DarkRed" style="color: White"/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="_IdItemHam" HeaderText="Item ID" SortExpression="_IdItemHam" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource9" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="item_code" HeaderText="Item Code" SortExpression="item_code" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="item_name" HeaderText="Item Name" SortExpression="item_name" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource2" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="item_group_name" HeaderText="Item Group Name" SortExpression="item_group_name" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource3" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="item_unit_name" HeaderText="Item Unit" SortExpression="item_unit_name" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource4" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="_Amount" HeaderText="Amount Needed" SortExpression="_Amount" ReadOnly="false" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource6" />
                    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="PROC" HeaderText="PROC" SortExpression="PROC" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource8" />--%>
                </Columns>
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

And here is my .cs code:

```cs
     protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            string amount = (row.Cells[6].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
            //DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
            //dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["Amount Needed"] = amount;
            //ViewState["dt"] = dt;
            ((StockRecipe.StockRecipeItemSet)ViewState["StockRecipeItemSet"]).RawMaterials.ElementAt(grdItems.EditIndex)._Amount = Double.Parse(amount);
            grdItems.EditIndex = -1;


            grdItems.DataSource = ((StockRecipe.StockRecipeItemSet)ViewState["StockRecipeItemSet"]).RawMaterials;
            grdItems.DataBind();

            CalculateProductCost();
        }
```

Can you please help me about how to make that event. Thanks from now!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the event OnRowUpdating, implemented in the GridView.
After that you can get the values and keys in the event, do your save statement and bind the grid.

```
      <asp:GridView ID="grdItems" runat="server" DataKeyNames="_IdItemHam" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="False" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="Horizontal"  
         OnRowUpdating="grdItems_RowUpdating">
```

.cs code:

```
     protected void grdItems_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e){
       object id = e.Keys["_IdItemHam"];
       int amount = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValues["_Amount"]);
       
       //Do your update statment
       
       //After that bind the grid 
       grdItems.DataBind();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

use GridView_RowCommand to implement edit action

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = 0;
GridViewRow row;
GridView grid = sender as GridView;

switch (e.CommandName)
{
    case "Edit":
        index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        row = grid.Rows[index];

        //use row to find the selected controls you need for edit, update, delete here

        break;
    }
}
```